# running a html and php on ubuntu

Tags: php, html, linux, ubuntu

I am new to HTML and PHP.

All I want to do is that I made a HTML file and a PHP file and now I want to test it on my local server i.e. my own computer. My HTML file includes the following code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
      <title>Codecademy Languages</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>Languages you can learn:</h1>
     <div class="wrapper">
       <ul>
       <?php include 'Test001.php'; ?>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and my PHP file named as Test001.php includes the following:

```
  <?php
      $langs = array("JavaScript",
      "HTML/CSS", "PHP",
      "Python", "Ruby");

      foreach ($langs as $lang) {
          echo "<li>$lang</li>";
      }

      unset($lang);
    ?>
```

How can I test the whole thing in my web browser? I am using Linux Ubuntu

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to install apache web server with PHP module :) This must help you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: I have installed it but I am still confused about how can I see my PHP file in the web browser.

Comment: @user3461530 How are you opening the file?

Comment: Just follow the tutorial I found  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: I am just opening the ".html" file in a browser, and when I try to open the ".php" file, it open in a text editor

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a substitute for reading installation instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you installed apache then go to /var/www directory. create a folder there . then paste your code files there .
then open a terminel .. and change the permission of folder. for your local project i suggest to give full permission as you are starter .. command is

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/your_folder_name  // use sudo in start if user not root
```

then open up a browser then go for link ...

```
localhost/your_folder_name/Test001.php
```

your must see output for your php file

Comment: This one worked perfectly. Thanks. Only another question is that if I have a ".css" file as will so shall i put it in the same folder and run PHP file or there is some other way to test the css?

Comment: no matter where you put it should be in your server i mean public folder and you properly link it to your files

Answer (score 0):

**First** you have to install some software, there is a software named "LAMP".

Here you can see the official ubuntu tutorial -> [Tutorial click here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lamp)

What is LAMP? LAMP is a box that contain some little software :

```
 - Server (apache2) : Entity that discuss with your browser
 - PHP5             : Install the langage
 - MySql            : Install the langage Mysql used to interact with BDD
```

**Second** you have to go into your brower and type "localhost" into *http://* input.

**Third** if you want to access to your html file, put it into */var/www* directory (in your computer) and access it using *http://* input.

```
Example :

 - Name of the file is '*toto.html*'
 - Type '*localhost/toto.html*' into *http://* input
```

If you have any questions about that, you are welcome buddy :)