# Ember do action on arrray push

Tags: ember.js, model, onchange

http://jsbin.com/qoyudape/4/edit

Every time you click update, item gets inserted. I would like to blink item red for one second after insertion, like on stackoverflow when linking to answer, it blinks orange for a second https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645880/1175593

How do I do that ?

Only CSS doesn't work, because I want the effect only on newly added items, and not on initial load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know CSS, but this, [Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load), seems to be just fine...

http://jsbin.com/qoyudape/6/edit

note, the render stuff I did isn't necessary, you could have just as easily done it without it...

http://jsbin.com/qoyudape/8/edit

or when the item is inserted into the page, you can do time sensitive animation

```
App.BlinkingFooView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
     if(this.get('controller.b') % 2 === 0){
       this.$().addClass('mod')
     } 
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/qoyudape/11/edit

Comment: And what if I wanted to apply an effect not available in CSS, is it possible with ember ?

Comment: Because I need to apply the effect just in certain cases, and not all the time.

Comment: There are a few places you could do this, here's a very common one.